# RecyclerView notifyxxx

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, notifydatasetchanged

Recently switched from `notifyDataSetChanged` to `notifyItemInserted/Changed/Removed` to preserve animations.

I'm stuck in this kind of situation. My adapter list initially is:

```
A
B
C
D
```

I then merge A, B and C to insert a new E item in last position:

```
A 
E
```

I thought I could notify index 1 (B) as removed, index 2 (C) as removed, index 3 (D) as removed and then the new index 1 (E) as inserted, but an exception coming from I don't know where says:

> Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter
>   positionViewHolder...

So I thought that maybe the problem was raised by notifying twice for index 1, so I changed it to notify index 1 (B) as changed to E, index 2 (C) as removed and index 3 (D) as removed, but the same exception was thrown, leaving me with no more options.

What should be the right approach in such a situation?

Comment: Have you tried DiffUtils?

Comment: It messes with the animations, like using notifyDataSetChanged. :(

Comment: It shouldnt, DiffUtils respects animations well. Anyway, if you can guarantee stable ids, you can use those with notifyDataSetChanged too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To not let question without answer in case someone else has the same problem

With Support library 24.2 [Diffutils](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.html) was released as a helpful class to calculate differences between two sets of items.

Sample code could look something like this (creating two lists and with press of button swapping the items in adapter). DiffUtil.DiffResult will handle all `notify` calls.

```
    final List<RecyclerObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new RecyclerObject("A"));
    list.add(new RecyclerObject("B"));
    list.add(new RecyclerObject("C"));
    list.add(new RecyclerObject("D"));

    final TestAdapter adapter = new TestAdapter(list);
    recycler.setAdapter(adapter);

    final List<RecyclerObject> newList = new ArrayList<>();
    newList.add(new RecyclerObject("A"));
    newList.add(new RecyclerObject("E"));

    final View button = findViewById(R.id.mainButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        adapter.setList(newList);

        DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(new DiffCallback(list, newList));
        diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(adapter);
    });
```

Diffcallback is own created class, implementation could look something like this. (unnecessary code removed for better readability)

```
public class DiffCallback extends DiffUtil.Callback {

    DiffCallback(final List<RecyclerObject> list, final List<RecyclerObject> newList) {
        this.list = list;
        this.newList = newList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getOldListSize() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getNewListSize() {
        return newList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areContentsTheSame(final int oldItemPosition, final int newItemPosition) {
        return list.get(oldItemPosition).title.equals(newList.get(newItemPosition).title);
    }

}
```

There is also one less fancy method : If we can guarantee that items backing the adapter are "stable" and same item will always have the same identificator, recycler.adapter allows for `setHasStableIds` option. With that, even using only `notifyDatasetChanged` (which normally kills animations) will correctly process them. Requires override of function `getItemId()`